# Custom payment method: Info Block cannot get data from From Block

Tags: checkout, blocks, payment, payment-methods

Today I am trying to create a custom payment method. Which requires user to fill in 2 fields and they all shows in the One-page Checkout Process. However, when I finished them and continue to the next step. The Info Block on the right side showed only the method title.

Please help.. Thank you a lot!

Below are my files:

Model:

```
<?php 
class Tai_Smartpay_Model_Smartpay extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
protected $_code = 'tai_smartpay';
protected $_formBlockType = 'tai_smartpay/form_smartpay';
protected $_infoBlockType = 'tai_smartpay/info_smartpay';

public function assignData($data)
{
    $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

    if ($data->getCustomFieldOne())
    {
        $info->setCustomFieldOne($data->getCustomFieldOne());
    }

    if ($data->getCustomFieldTwo())
    {
        $info->setCustomFieldTwo($data->getCustomFieldTwo());
    }

    return $this;
}
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
    return Mage::getUrl('tai_smartpay/payment/redirect', array('_secure' => false));
}
```

Block Form:

```
<?php
class Tai_Smartpay_Block_Form_Smartpay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('tai_smartpay/form/smartpay.phtml');
}
}
```

Info Block:

```
?php
class Tai_Smartpay_Block_Info_Smartpay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{
protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
{
    if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation)
    {
        return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
    }

    $data = array();
    if ($this->getInfo()->getCustomFieldOne())
    {
        $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Custom Field One')] = $this->getInfo()->getCustomFieldOne();
    }

    if ($this->getInfo()->getCustomFieldTwo())
    {
        $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Custom Field Two')] = $this->getInfo()->getCustomFieldTwo();
    }

    $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);

    Zend_Debug::dump($this->getInfo()->getCustomFieldOne());

    return $transport->setData(array_merge($data, $transport->getData()));
}
}
```

and Template:

```
<div class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
<div>
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Custom Field One') ?>*</label>
<span>
  <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Custom Field One') ?>" name="payment[custom_field_one]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getInfoData('custom_field_one')) ?>" />
</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label><?php echo $this->__('Custom Field Two') ?>*</label>
<span>
  <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Custom Field Two') ?>" name="payment[custom_field_two]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getInfoData('custom_field_two')) ?>" />
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<?php echo $this->getMethod()->getConfigData('message');?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it, the code is correct. It's because of my cache. When I restart my computer. It works. However, I still don't know what kind of cache caused this problem, because I have disabled all the cache inside the Admin Config :/